# Get delegate function for arbitrary java method

Tags: java, functional-programming, mockito, guava

Is there an easy way to get an arbitrary `Function` version of a method on a POJO?

For example:

```
FluentIterable.from(myCollection).uniqueIndex(Functions.for(Item.class).getId)
                     .first(Predicates.equalTo(id)).get();
```

Where `Functions.for` ideally behaves like `Mockito.mock`

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can use [lambdaj](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/) which is

> a library that makes easier to address this issue by allowing to
>   manipulate collections in a pseudo-functional and statically typed
>   way.

Lambdaj *does* similar tricks as Mockito, so you should read its [limitations](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/wiki/KnownLimitations) (most important is that your POJO must not be final).

With lambdaj, your code could be something like this (note that `uniqueIndex` from your example returns `Map`, which does not have `first` method, so I'll guess here):

```
import ch.lambdaj.Lambda.*; // for all static methods used below

// just items indexed by their ids
Map<Intgeger, Item> indexed = index(myCollection, on(Item.class).getId());
// or more likely you want
Item foundItem = selectFirst(
     myCollection, having(on(Item.class).getId(), equalTo(id)));
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not how Java works.

However, with Java 8, you can use a method reference to create a lambda:

```
FluentIterable.from(myCollection).uniqueIndex(Item::getId)
        .first(Predicates.equalTo(id)).get();
```

Comment: FYI: Java can work in that way, with some serious hacks. For example `Mockito.mock(Item.class).getId()`

Comment: `getId()` (with the parentheses) and `getId` (without) are 2 different things, the second one (as you wrote in your question) doesn't exist. I know Mockito.